# Android save data files to app-specific directory

Tags: android, directory

I have put together a small app which will take a picture and then Save the Image file out to the External Storage.
I have the permissions set in the Manifest.
And it is working (sort of...).

BUT it is saving the files to the 'root' of the MyFiles directory
( **/storage/emulated/0** )
not to my app-specific directory
( **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app** )
and I don't want to go to an SD card location.

Currently I am using

```
private File mLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.jpg");
```

to establish the pathed file name.
And, as I said, that is working - only going to the wrong directory location.

Obviously I should be doing something different, but I don't know what to change and the other postings on the general topic I have found are not clearly presented such that I can 'interpret' from them what I need to change.

Your advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use getExternalFilesDir() instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately when I attempt to use that I get a **Cannot resolve method 'getExternalFilesDir(null)'**

Answer (score 0):

```
private File mLocation  = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "test.jpg");
```

[read this article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  As I commented above - when I attempted to use that I got a **Cannot resolve method 'getExternalFilesDir(null)'**

Comment: you should use   mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) where mContext is the Context variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well I saw where I was not specifically following your suggestions and therefore I changed the code from:

```
(Environment.getExternalFilesDir(null), "test.jpg")
```

to

```
(getExternalFilesDir(null), "test.jpg")
```

And the error message went away.
BUT now the app crashes immediately before getting up and running.